# Excel: Matching Data in Excel. Writing an IF statement by dragging instead of manually inputting

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office

I have two sheets. Both sheets contains two columns with Countries and Price #s. The first sheet does not have info for the Price # but the second does.

Sheet 1:

**Country|Price #**

Canada   | Null

Brazil   | Null

Spain    | Null

Canada   | Null

Sheet 2:

**Country|Price #**

Canada   | 1

Spain    | 2

Brazil   | 3

Austria  | 4

Goal: I want to fill out the Null values in sheet 1 with the corresponding numbers in sheet two. For example a 1 for Canada, 3 for Brazil, etc.

If I didn't have much data, this would be an easy IF statement in the Null cell. For example 
' =IF(B2="Canada",1, IF(B2="Spain",2,IF(B2="Brazil",3,4)))

Problem is that my data contains over 50 countries so it would be tedious to write this formula. Is there a way to use the drag feature in Excel to do this? Also open to not using an IF statement.

Comment: You are looking for either [`INDEX`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDEX-function-A5DCF0DD-996D-40A4-A822-B56B061328BD)/[`MATCH`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-E8DFFD45-C762-47D6-BF89-533F4A37673A) or [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0BBC8083-26FE-4963-8AB8-93A18AD188A1)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use `SUMPRODUCT`if you need return numbers only:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(D1=$A$1:$A$4)*$B$1:$B$4)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sheet2:

[image]

Sheet formula Pict 1:

[image]

Sheet Formula Pict 2:

[image]

Here the formula to be copied, choose as your need:

```
=filter(if(C1:C="",vlookup(B1:B,Sheet2!A1:B,2,false),""),B1:B<>"")
```

or

```
=filter(vlookup(B1:B,Sheet2!A1:B,2,false),B1:B<>"")
```

Comment: if FILTERXML the same as "filter" ? This formula is not working for me.